# How to unscrew this vacuum cleaner's motor axis?

Tags: electric-motor, vacuum

How can I unscrew the central axis from my vacuum cleaner's motor. It appears it is sealed with some sort of green substance and it doesn't move at all. I already tried dissolving it with acetone and WD-40 and had no luck. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: looks like a locknut that you need to apply some torque to. Also see if you can lock down the axle to stop it rotating as you try and unbolt it

Answer (score 3):

Heat is a common method to make threadlockers let go - some specifically require it. Odds are excellent that it's [Loctite Green](https://www.henkel-adhesives.com/us/en/products/industrial-adhesives/threadlockers.html) or a knock-off of that. That specifically mentions "heat and hand tools" implying that it should not need high impact to remove once you heat it up.

Comment: If locktight some heat and it may spin right off keep in mind it may be a left hand thread also.